# Snowflake Task - Evaluate System Variable at Creation time

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to boilerplate a task creation script, by setting a dynamic name.

eg...

```
set cat_id = 123;
DECLARE
    task_name varchar;
BEGIN
    if ($cat_id = 123) then
        set task_name := 'prod.tasks.task_cat_a';
    elseif ($cat_id = 456) then
        set task_name := 'prod.tasks.task_cat_b';
    elseif ($cat_id = 789) then
        set task_name := 'prod.tasks.task_cat_c';
    end if;

set the_task_name = :task_name;

END;

create or replace task identifier($the_task_name)
    schedule='USING CRON 0 20 * * * Australia/Sydney'
    USER_TASK_MANAGED_INITIAL_WAREHOUSE_SIZE='XSMALL'
    as
...
```

This itself works great.

However I then want that same `cat_id` to be referenced inside the TASK, but evaluated at the time the task is created.

eg,

```
create or replace task identifier($the_task_name)
    schedule='USING CRON 0 20 * * * Australia/Sydney'
    USER_TASK_MANAGED_INITIAL_WAREHOUSE_SIZE='XSMALL'
    as

DECLARE
  rows_count INT;
  export_path varchar;
  cat_id_num int;
  file_suffix varchar;
BEGIN

    cat_id_num := $cat_id;
    return :cat_id_num;

END;
```

But this *doesn't* work, as the string `cat_id_num := $cat_id;` gets added to the task, but of course the variable `$cat_id` no longer exists when the task is executed.

Instead, I'm looking for a way where when I run the script to create the task, the variable `$cat_id` gets evaluated, such that the task gets created with

```
cat_id_num := 123;
```

Is this something that's achievable?

Comment: Have you tried creating the `create task` statement dynamically as a string and then executing that statement after it has been built?  This would allow the variable to be substituted with a value when the string is generated.

Comment: @MikeWalton, I haven't, but it's a good shout; I'll give that a go.